# Getting Error: Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entilement

Tags: ios, swift4.1

I have created an ios app that uses healthkit functionality to get health-related data to my ios app. Well, my app works well in the simulator and also on iPhone device.
But when I create an IPA file of ios app, run on iPhone device, it shows error Missing `com.apple.developer.healthkit entilement`.
I am using Cydia impactor to deploy IPA file on a device.

Comment: Have you enabled `Healthkit` from capabilities? @ManishaThorat

Comment: yes, i enabled it

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/abdul002/iOS-health-populate-mindfulness-swift-3-4zkz0ib1v . I used this blog as reference.

Comment: maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993314/how-to-solve-this-error-with-healthkit) help you.

Comment: i didn't get second point.your app id associated with your provisioning profile has healthkit turned on and matches the app's bundle id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I an trying to deploy an ipa file using free developer account.
I resolved this with paid apple developer account.
thank you